# Return a tuple from a function and place into another function python

Tags: python

This description may be a bit complicated so I will try to keep it short.

I have the following code that is working correctly...

```
def singlelist():
    from datetime import datetime
    from subprocess import Popen
    from subprocess import PIPE
    output=Popen(["sar","-r"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
    date=datetime.now()
    date=str(date).split()[0]
    listtimeval=[]
    for line in output.split('\n'):
        if line == '' or 'Average' in line or 'kb' in line or 'Linux' in line or 'RESTART' in line:
            pass
        else:
            (time,ampm,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7) = line.split()
            listtimeval.append((time + " "+ ampm + "," + field3).split(','))
    updatelist= [ [str(date) + " " +x[0],x[1]] for x in listtimeval]
    return updatelist


val=singlelist()
```

...notice how time,ampm,etc are not defined previously...

I am trying to make this more dynamic as the output of sar will not always have the same number of columns.

What I want to do is this...

```
def fields(method):
    if method == '-r':
        nf = (time,ampm,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7)
    return nf


def singlelist(nf):
    from datetime import datetime
    from subprocess import Popen
    from subprocess import PIPE
    output=Popen(["sar","-r"], stdout=PIPE).communicate()[0]
    date=datetime.now()
    date=str(date).split()[0]
    listtimeval=[]
    for line in output.split('\n'):
        if line == '' or 'Average' in line or 'kb' in line or 'Linux' in line or 'RESTART' in line:
            pass
        else:
            nf = line.split()
            listtimeval.append((time + " "+ ampm + "," + field3).split(','))
    updatelist= [ [str(date) + " " +x[0],x[1]] for x in listtimeval]
    return updatelist

method='-r'
nf=fields(method)
val=singlelist(nf)
```

However I am getting this...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./Logic.py", line 110, in <module>
    nf=fields(method)
  File "./Logic.py", line 58, in fields
    nf = (time,ampm,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7)
NameError: global name 'time' is not defined
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Where is the function supposed to get those names?

Answer (score 0):

- You haven't defined `time` in your `fields` function. Well, none of `(time,ampm,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7)` is defined in that function...
- You don't use `nf` in `singlelist`, except to reallocate it. What are you trying to achieve ?
- You could modify `fields` to accept the parameters `(time,ampm,field1,field2,field3,field4,field5,field6,field7)` along your `method` argument, but how would you define them? You would still have to call `fields` from `singlelist`.

Comment: The old function was working correctly without defining these variables prior to using them. However I want to have a different list of variables each time so for sar -u the fields would be different than sar -r

Comment: Also, I updated the comment, forgot to remove the reference to nf in singlelist in the first example

Answer (score 0):

Following up on Pierre's answer: you can assign TO an undeclared variable (implicitly creating it), you cannot assign FROM it without getting an undefined variable error.

You also seem to be making that poor function do an awful lot of unrelated things - loading modules, calling subprocesses, parsing and reparsing data. It might be easier to understand and maintain if you break it up as follows:

```
import datetime
from itertools import izip
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

def call_sar(options, columns):
    sar  = Popen(["sar"]+options, stdout=PIPE)  # create subprocess
    res  = sar.communicate()[0]                 # get stdout text
    data = res.splitlines()[3:-1]               # grab the relevant lines
    return (dict(izip(columns, row.split())) for row in data)

def get_system_stats(mode, fmt=None):
    modes = {   # different ways to call sar, and the values returned by each
        "all_cpus": ('-r',    'time ampm cpu user_pct nice_pct system_pct iowait_pct steal_pct idle_pct'),
        "each_cpu": ('-P',    'time ampm cpu user_pct nice_pct system_pct iowait_pct steal_pct idle_pct'),
        "mem":      ('-r',    'time ampm memfree_kb memused_kb memused_pct buffers_kb cached_kb commit_kb commit_pct active_kb inactive_kb'),
        "swap":     ('-S',    'time ampm swapfree_kb swapused_kb swapused_pct swapcad_kb swapcad_pct'),
        "all_io":   ('-b',    'time ampm ts read_ts write_ts read_bs write_bs'),
        "each_io":  ('-p -d', 'time ampm dev ts read_ss write_ss avg_req_sz avg_queue_sz avg_wait'),
        "switch":   ('-w',    'time ampm proc_s switch_s'),
        "queue":    ('-q',    'runq_sz plist_sz avg_load_1 avg_load_5 avg_load_15 blocked')
    }
    if mode in modes:
        options, columns = modes[mode]
        data = call_sar(options.split(), columns.split())
        if fmt is None:
            # return raw data (list of dict)
            return list(data)
        else:
            # return formatted data (list of str)
            return [fmt.format(**d) for d in data]
    else:
        raise ValueError("I don't know mode '{}'".format(mode))
```

Now you can easily define your function like so:

```
def single_list():
    today = datetime.datetime.now().date()
    fmt   = "{} {} {} {}".format(today, '{time}', '{ampm}', '{memused_pct}')
    return get_system_stats("mem", fmt)
```

Note: I am writing this on a Windows 7 machine, so I don't have sar and can't actually run-test it - it has no syntax errors, and I *think* it should work properly as-is, but it may need minor tweaking.